# Javascript Calendar Sandbox

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm searching for a JS framework similar to the GoogleCalendar interface. I'm most interested in dragging and dropping boxes, shrinking and expanding them, and having them auto-resize if there is a time conflict.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be helpful for you: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/